# Praying whilst breastfeeding

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women

If a woman is suitably dressed in a modest manner and is covered to the greatest degree possible, would she be permitted to pray whilst breastfeeding?

If yes, would this be reserved for sha'at hadchak or can she do this lechatchila?

Comment: I would think Kavanah would come into play here.

Comment: http://www.din.org.il/2013/10/15/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%94/

Answer (score 6):

Rav Elayshiv(Vayishma Moshe pg40) was asked if one can daven while nursing and he answered yes as long as the areas which are usually covered are covered.

Answer (score 3):

The Ben Ish Chai Shana Alef Parshas Bo 10 he writes that a man cannot pray even if it is his own wife if she is exposed while breastfeeding.However,he brings that there are those who hold that since it is usual to expose that area while nursing then during nursing it can be considered an area which is usually uncovered and would be permissible.He notes that this should be only done in a pressing need.

One may extrapolate from this halacha that a woman herself may be lenient.

One must ask a Rov for halacha lmaaseh,logic from oneself is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

see mishnah berura 75 3
 ולכן צריך ליזהר בשעה שמינקת ומגולה דדיה שלא לדבר אז שום דברי קדושה 
obviously is she is covered there would be no problem

regarding the husband see rabbi falks book levushah shel torah vol 1 pg and hebrew version oz vehadar levusha pg 347