# Bracha on breastmilk?

Tags: blessing, chinuch-education, dairy

Should a child old enough to make brachos who is not weaned be encouraged to make a bracha on breastmilk? If so which one? Are there any direct sources for this?

Comment: "Which one." Well it would have to be shehakol. That's what anyone drinking any milk says.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31292/759

Comment: I seem to remember a story of a child of Reb Aryeh Leib Levin who made such a brocho but I can't find it now.

Comment: The better question is what bracha does an adult make since it is mutar if its in a cup or his hands.

Comment: @sam i seem to remember this still being 'bal teshaktzu' for an adult

Comment: That is urine your thinking of

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It's in his short autobiography in the intro to A Tzaddik in Our Times.  The child passed away before he turned 2, IIRC.

Comment: Al netillat shadayim

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 81:7 that one has to stop nursing by age 4 or 5 if child is weak.

The Shulchan Aruch in 167:19, see also Mishna Brurah 269:1 who holds the age of chinuch is 6 or 7.

so it seems that a bracha should not be recited at all.

Comment: I must be missing it; I see no discussion of age in OC 167:19

Comment: The Mishna Berura says it all depends on the child's ability, so even five years old might be possible, and moreover he is referring to chinuch for havdalla which might be later than chinuch on shehakol. If you want to claim the OP's situation is impossible, you'd better do a better job proving it is so.

Comment: I didn't see כבר שית כבר שבע mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch itself.

Comment: There are many opinions on this matter,I wrote it seems,not the word impossible.

Comment: @sam If you agree the OP's case is possible, then what kind of answer is this?

Comment: Mishna Brurah 128:123 ללמוד ולהתחנך - ומטעם זה רשאי לברך ג"כ מ"א וכ"כ הרדב"ז בח"א בסי' תקס"ה. וחינוך זה אינו כשאר זמני החנוך שהוא כבר חמש כבר שית כ"א בשיודע לישא כפיו כמנהגי הכהנים:

Comment: @doubleaa , http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9158&st=&pgnum=274&hilite= it seems that 5 or 6 is the age of chinuch

Comment: You mean to say it is the *average* age of chinuch according to him. Why is that relevant?

Comment: It seems from a bunch of sources that 5 and 6 are the age of chinuch. The question should be about an adult not a child.

Comment: If the child is old enough to make brachos and does so on other foods? What the question should or could be be is an entirely different matter. Should a capable but "too young" child just not be encouraged to make brachos in general?

Comment: @Sam It doesn't matter what age children are expected to stop nursing, as even adults may drink breastmilk as long as it has been put in a cup first.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but some adaptations must be made for technical reasons.

One should not say a beracha before the food or drink is before him

BUT

One may not say a beracha when there is an exposed breast present.

Ergo, one may not say a beracha on breast milk unless perhaps he first observes the breast, then goes behind a mechitza to say the beracha.

Comment: -1 many people _can_ say blessings in front of exposed breasts.

Comment: who  may say blessing in front of exposed breasts (except for perhaps blind people)

Comment: Women.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: May she look at other people's breasts or only her own?

I thought one isn't allowed to say any brachot or words of torah naked?

Comment: Breasts aren't genitals...

Comment: @Double AA being that breasts are a hirhur problem and not an erva problem can't we assume that a little boy may also make a bracha before exposed breasts?

Comment: @user6591 I think that is quite reasonable

Comment: @Double AA now I need to find that Ibn Ezra. I recall him saying that rebelious behavior in children begins at the onslaught of puberty, which itself only begins when a child begins to have daas, chinuch age. That would make the discussion on the other answer very exciting as well.